# Алгоритмы. Python. 2 больших списка, проставить индексы соответствия

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, индексация, индексы

Пишу на Python
Есть 2 списка. Один статический, находится в таблице Excel. Второй список парсится с сайта, парсятся уникальные номера товаров, вида "3593893".

На данный момент я сначала нахожу все уникальные номера на сайте (Порядка 3000 штук). Засовываю их в список.
Затем засовываю во второй список все номера из Excel.

И мне нужно найти в какой строке в таблице Excel находится одинаковый номер из первого списка.
Из-за того что строк порядка 3000, то моя конструкция работает очень долго, больше часа.
Я использую что-то вроде:

```
for i in range(0, len(ids)):
   if ids[i] in codes_data:
       j = codes_data.index(ids[i])
       #"заполняю строку остальными данными"
```

Правильно ли я понимаю что программа в данном случае просматривает список "codes_data" дважды?

Первый раз в `if ids[i] in codes_data` Второй раз в `codes_data.index(ids[i])`

Если это так, то корректно ли сделать:

```
for i in range(0, len(ids)):
    try:
        j = codes_data.index(ids[i])
        #"заполняю строку остальными данными"
    except: pass
```

В таком случае получается список codes_data просматривается один раз и программа будет работать быстрее и лучше?

Можно ли как-то ускорить нахождение индексов?
Думал что как-то можно использовать сортировку, чтобы отталкиваться от неё, но не уверен что это самый простой и самый быстрый способ.

---

Обновление.
Проблема была решена. Главная проблема как оказывается была в другом. Я слишком часто сохранял Excel файл, что тормозило работу программы. После того как я сделал отдельный файл для считывания и отдельный для записи, скорость стала молниеносной.
Но я также смог улучшить и обработку списков благодаря ответам ниже, что еще больше улучшило пограмму.
Спасибо.

Comment: Сделайте второй список множеством (set). Перебираете список, проверяете наличие каждого элемента во множестве

Comment: @АлексейР
set немного не подходит к сожалению.
У меня есть несколько списков.
Списком ids[i] я нахожу номер строки куда нужно писать значение 'j', а затем в эту строку вношу i'ые элементы других списков (Цена, название, количество)
Я пытался применить set и к первому и ко второму списку. Ничего не вышло. Set является неупорядоченным списком, что не позволит мне узнать либо 'i', либо 'j'

Comment: а у вас в питонах есть словари? Например, составить словарь, где ключ - ваше число, а значение - индекс числа в том списке.

Comment: @tym32167 Словари есть, обязательно опробую это

Comment: Есть возможность получить оба списка в виде файлов, чтобы проверить алгоритм на данных, приближенных к реальным?

Comment: Не могу понять, откуда часы??? Сделал два случайных списка по 3000 элементов в каждом. Заполнил случайными строками из цифр по 12 в каждом элементе .  Запустил. Время выполнения  примерно 0.1секунда. Одна десятая секунды. Откуда берутся часы???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена. Главная проблема как оказывается была в другом. Я слишком часто сохранял Excel файл, что тормозило работу программы. После того как я сделал отдельный файл для считывания и отдельный для записи, скорость стала молниеносной.

Но я также смог улучшить и обработку списков благодаря ответам в вопросе, что еще больше улучшило программу. Спасибо.

Comment: О чем я вам и написал в комментарии под вашим вопросом. Но вот еще одна подсказка вам, как новичку на сайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться.

Answer (score 0):

Оптимизированная версия алгоритма автора:

```
for i, value in enumerate(ids):
    try:
        j = codes_data.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        j = None

    if j is not None:
        #"заполняю строку остальными данными"
        # используя полученный i
```

В блоке try код заполнения писать не стоит. Код в блоке try должен быть как можно компактнее.

P.S. Если использовать словарь для данных из Excel, то можно обойтись без поиска j и сразу формировать строку с данными в словаре.

Comment: зачем делать ``if j is None:  continue else: заполнять`` если просто ``if j: заполнять`` делает то же самое

Comment: Я в курсе, что if j: делает то же самое. Но где гарантия что в j когда-нибудь придет не None или не int? Выражение if j: эквивалентно if bool(j):, но на bool может возникнуть исключение. Сделано для надежности. Плюс PEP8 рекомендует для None использовать is. Но Ваш вариант тоже рабочий. Вы вольны выбрать любой.

Comment: какое исключение может возникнуть на bool()? А гарантия, что в j будет или None или число находится в предыдущих строчках кода.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в Интернете как можно bool загнать в исключение. Понятно, что в данном простеньком алгоритме такого никогда не возникнет и на всех стандартных типах bool срабатывает штатно всегда, но я предпочитаю писать код с запасом прочности. Таков мой стиль. Ваш стиль тоже прекрасен и я ни к коем случае не ставлю под сомнение в работоспособности Ваш вариант.

Comment: да конструкция ``if что-нибудь:  continue`` сама по себе нелепая.

Comment: Уже исправил. Спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 0):

Поиск элемента в списке имеет сложность `O(n)`, а в словаре `O(1)`.

Чтобы сильно не переписывать код, можно сделать по-быстрому маппинг в виде словаря `item -> position` и использовать его для поиска позиций:

```py
codes_dict = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(codes_data)}

for id_ in ids:
    j = codes_dict.get(id_)
    if j is not None:
        #"заполняю строку остальными данными"
        ...
```

Метод `get` возвращает либо значение из словаря, если такой ключ в словаре есть, либо `None`, если ключа нет. Таким образом, можно достать значение и проверить наличие ключа в словаре одной операцией вместо двух, дополнительная экономия. Хотя при сложности доставания элемента из словаря `O(1)` это уже будет не так существенно влиять на скорость кода, но всё-таки.

А в вашем коде да - если элемент есть в списке, то список просматривается два раза - один раз при проверке наличия элемента и второй раз чтобы получить индекс этого элемента. Учитывая сложность обеих операций `O(n)` получается довольно "медленно и печально".

Comment: Одно НО: i нужен из ids, а не из codes_data, насколько я понял автора вопроса.

Comment: @VladimirBogdanov Так `i` вообще не нужно, по крайней мере в приведённом автором вопроса коде

Comment: @CrazyElfЦитата:  вношу i'ые элементы других списков (Цена, название, количество)ю А что если:   codes_dict = {x: j for j, x in enumerate(codes_data)}

for i, id_ in enumerate(ids):
    j = codes_dict.get(id_)
    if j is not None:
        #"заполняю строку остальными данными", используя полученный i

Comment: @VladimirBogdanov Не обязательно перебирать номера элементов списка, чтобы получить эти элементы. Можно перебирать сразу сами элементы списка, что я и делаю, собственно.

Comment: Со всем, что написано про словарь, я полностью согласен. В своем примере я тоже рекомендовал использовать словарь. Но нужно учитывать требования автора вопроса. Насколько я понял, кроме ids есть набор списков, которые синхронизированы по индексу из ids, тот самый i. Нужно найти номер строки в Excel, та самая j, и дополнить информацией из списков по индексу i. При этом i и j не равны. Я бы сразу выгрузил Excel в словарь с ключом по номеру товара, а в качестве значения либо список, либо еще один словарь. Далее итерировал список ids и сразу вносил в словарь из Excel все данные по ключу.